# why c++ auto object optimization is happening in this code?

Tags: c++

Why only one object of A is created in this program? and no copy constructor is called. What is this optimization called? If this is a valid/known optimization, will it not be a trouble for multiton design pattern?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        A () {
            cout << "in-- Constructor A" << endl;
            ++as;
        }

        A (const A &a) {
            cout << "in-- Copy-Constructor A" << endl;
            ++as;
        }

        ~A() {
            cout << "out --Constructor A" << endl;
            --as;
        }

        A & operator=(const A &a) {
            cout << "assignment" << endl;
            ++as;
            //return *this;
        }

        static int as;
};
int A::as = 0;


A fxn() {
    A a;
    cout << "a: " << &a << endl;
    return a;
}

int main() {

    A b = fxn();
    cout << "b: " << &b << endl;

    cout << "did destructor of object a in func fxn called?" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of above program

```
in-- Constructor A
a: 0x7fffeca3bed7
b: 0x7fffeca3bed7
did destructor of object a in func fxn called?
out --Constructor A
```

Comment: this is called RVO. In this case NRVO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through link http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/ 
It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case of a [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization). This optimization is notable in the C++ world as *it is allowed to change the observable behavior of the program*. It's one of the few, if not the only, optimization that's allowed to do that, and it's from the days where returning copies was considered a weakness. (With move semantics and generally faster machines, this is much, much less of an issue now.)

Basically, the compiler sees that it's going to copy the object, so instead it allocates room for it on the calling frame and then builds it there instead of calling the copy constructor.

Comment: and what about multiton design pattern?

Comment: Yes and what about multiton design pattern?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be trouble for it. You specifically don't want to copy objects with the multiton pattern that I know of.